# UITableView Deleted Cell Reuse Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm having an issue when deleting cells in my table view. It appears that whenever a cell is deleted, the next cell displayed on the screen does not show. I have debugged `cellForRowAt` and the cell is being dequeued and the data set, but the table view cell is never rendered. Here is my relevant code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "taskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskTableViewCell
    if let task = self.task(indexPath: indexPath) {
        cell.update(task: task)
    }
    cell.checkChanged = ...
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    guard let task = self.task(indexPath: indexPath) else {
            return nil
    }

    var actions = [UIContextualAction]()

    let delete = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: LocStr("delete")) { [unowned self] (action, view, success) in
        self.delete(indexPath: indexPath)
        success(true)
    }

    actions.append(delete)

    ...

    let configuration = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: actions)
    return configuration
}

func delete(indexPath: IndexPath) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
        if let task = self.task(indexPath: indexPath) {
            self.allTasks.removeAll(where: { $0.id == task.id })
            self.sort()
            ...
            self.tableView.beginUpdates()
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
            self.tableView.endUpdates()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: missing table view cell]

As you can see, when I scroll through the table view, the next cell is empty even though `cellForRowAt` is called for that cell. I debugged the UI and was able to confirm that there is no cell in the empty space.

[image: debugged ui]

Has anyone else had this issue? Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you wrapping your `delete` method in `DispatchQueue.main.async`? Does it work without that?

Comment: The delete can possibly be called from another event that may or may not be on the main thread. I have not included that code here because that event is not what is causing the delete in this testing. I have removed the `DispatchQueue.main.async` to test and the issue is still there.

Comment: the height is `UITableView.automaticDimension` (so dynamic)

Comment: Tried with a static height of 60 and still get the empty space. I've also debugged the UI and there are no table view cells there.

Comment: I cannot find official documentation on this, but some sources say that you should **not** call `tableView.deleteRows` when using a `.destructive` style.

Comment: WOW. Removing the `.destructive` style worked. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake You have it backwards. Don't remove the `.destructive` style. Keep that. The change you need to make is to avoid calling `deleteRows` if you are using `.destructive` style and passing `true` to the `success` closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot find official documentation on this, but I believe you should not call `tableView.deleteRows` when using a `.destructive` style.